# Use Ruby to make a DrRacket `append` function

Tags: ruby

I am trying to use Ruby to emulate an `append` function from DrRacket. However, when I try it, I get `((1 2 3) . 99)` instead of `(1 2 3 . 99)`. Is it possible to correctly emulated `append` with a preexisting list, or do I need to make a copy of it first? Please reply at your earliest convenience.

Comment: Please make sure to construct a [mre]. Note that all three of those words are important: it should be an *example* only, you should not post your entire actual code, rather you should create a simplified example that demonstrates your problem. Also, it should be *minimal*, i.e. it should not contain anything that is not absolutely required to demonstrate the problem. (Most beginner problems can be demonstrated in less than 5 short simple lines of code.) And it should be *reproducible*, which means that if I copy&paste and run the code, I should see the exact same problem you see.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: Must we reverse-engineer your code to try to understand your first sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two points to your problem:

1. Data Structure

`append` is basically like `cons`, in the sense of it should also add items to the underlying *list*. However in this example, it actually returns a string, without altering the state of the `Pair` object.

What you actually need to do, is to `append` the new item to the end of the `pair/list` structure. To achieve this you need to walk through the pairs (assuming it is a valid list) until you find the last item, which should be `null`.

```
 def append(other)
  return false unless list?
  
  if cdr.nil?
    @value2 = other
  else
    cdr.append(other)
  end

  self
end
```

It is also important that you return the "existing" object with `self` if you want to `puts` inline, like in your example.

Take for example the following code:

```
b = cons(1, Pair.null)
c = cons(4, Pair.null)

puts b.append(c)
```

`append` here will make sure that the following structure is created:

```
<Pair @value1=1, @value2=<Pair @value1=4, @value2=nil>>
```

2. Printing the `list`

Now, in order to print the list it is yet another recursive problem (like the first one). You need to walk through the list of pairs but also account for the the different cases. That's why keeping a valid data structure in place is so important.

```
def to_s
  helper_to_s(true)
end

def helper_to_s(started = false)
  str = ""
  str += "(" if started
  str += "(" if started && car.is_a?(Pair)

  if car.is_a?(Pair)
      str += car.helper_to_s
  else
    str += car.to_s
  end

  if cdr.nil?
    str += ")"
  elsif cdr.is_a?(Pair)
    str += " "
    str += cdr.helper_to_s()
  else
    str += " . #{cdr})"
  end

  str
end
```

We need a `helper function` so that we can tell the recursion call when to `open` the `(`. Additionally we also need to account for the case when we have nested pair right away. Finally, thanks to our data structure we can tell when the cdr is not `null`, meaning it's not a `pure list`, in this case we can simply concatenate a `.` to the final string and it will show it properly in the `to_s` call.

If you have further questions please make sure to check the documentation for Pairs and List in the racket documentation: https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Pairs__Lists__and_Racket_Syntax.html it is really helpful.